# Ищу хранилище данных

Tags: c++, hpc

Ищу библиотеку (возможно, базу данных, или key-value storage, или HPC data storage?) для хранения данных, со следующими характеристиками:

1. Данные представляют собой таблицы с очень большим числом колонок (десятки тысяч). Данные только одного типа (64-бит, с плавающей точкой). Потеря точности при хранении данных не допускается. Объем каждой таблицы может достигать десятков Gb.
2. Для колонок, кроме данных и названия, хранятся атрибуты, например, единицы измерения. (Это можно решить сложносочиненным названием колонки, не не хотелось бы.)
3. Писатели не редактируют записанныйе данные, а могут только создать таблицу, и добавлять строки.
   Все писатели знают структуру таблиц, и если таблицу (с одним именем) захотят создать несколько писателей, можно быть уверенным, что структура таблиц - одинакова.
4. Один читатель, много писателей. Читатели/писатели - отдельные процессы, в пределах одной машины. (Если возможна работа в пределах одного MPI кластера, или в пределах одной файловой системы - будет большой плюс.)
5. Писатели стартуют и завершаются не одновременно (это не обязательно MPI процессы).
6. Читателя интересуют не все данные одновременно, а отдельный набор колонок или строк (несколько десятков). Также, иногда, интересует статистика по колонкам (минимальное/максимальное значение, сумма, число NaN-ов).
7. Скорость записи имеет приоритет, перед скоростью чтения. (Т.е. GUI-читатель мог бы и подождать, а пистелей тормозить нежелательно.)

На первый взгляд, мне нужна база данных (на базе memory-mapped files, в случае работы на одной машине, и сетевая в случае MPI кластера). Но требование на бешеное число колонок - сбивает: в просмотренных мной движках оно ограничено, максимум тысячами.

Смотрел, также, в сторону HDF5, но там возможно только "один писатель-несколько читателей" (мне нужно наоборот).

Сейчас я использую велосипед, на базе множества бинарных файлов (каждый писатель пишет в ской файл, а читатель их "виртуально" склевает). Но это неудобно: приходится самому реализовать сбор статистики мо колонкам, мониторинг изменения файлов и т.д.

Что-то похоже должно быть в использовано кластерных счетных программах. Смотрел в сторону OpenFOAM, но там, похоже, все слишком завязано на 3d-геометрию.

Какое еще хранилище данных было бы здесь применимо?

Comment: я не хочу изображать "знатока", но в последних версиях монги появились такие вкусные аггрегации... которые, каежтся, полностью покрывают хотелки по "статистике по колонкам". Осталось понять - подходит ли монга с других точек зрения, но теоретически если считать что строка - это "документ" - то вроде получается. А Вы монгу не пробовали?

Comment: @S.H. Если каждую колонку посылать как отдельное поле BSON-а, то получится очень большой оверхед по памяти. А, если массив из double хранить как одно поле, то я не смогу собирать статистику по колонкам. Или смогу?  К тому же, как я понял из описания, сбор статистики не ведется, а функция agregation - просто пост-обработка данных. Агрегация может использовать пре-собранные данные, только если есть соответствующий индекс. Но число индексов на коллекцию - ограничено.

Comment: Писатели пишут строками? Т.е. одна запись помещает данные во все десятки тысяч колонок?

Comment: @avp Сейчас - да. Иногда, даже десятками или сотнями строчек с малым интеравалом времени между ними. Можно.безболезненно увеличить число строк посылку до десятков строк.